# Where is this logging to?

Tags: python, logging, python-logging

I have this Python code:

```
import logging
LOGGER = logging.getLogger(__name__)
LOGGER.info('test')
```

It does not get written to the console, so where does this get logged?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does not get logged anywhere, because you did not configure any [handlers](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html) for the logging framework. Without a handler configured, the log event just gets dropped.

When there aren't any handlers configured, if an event at WARNING or above is seen the root logger will get a handler added automatically, but your event was just at INFO level so that doesn't happen here.

If you include a line like this beforehand to configure the logging framework, then you will see the INFO event logged to terminal:

```
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
```

Using basic config will add a [`StreamHandler`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#streamhandler) writing to [`sys.stderr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.stderr) if you don't specify otherwise.